# Como puedo factorizar este código?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo 4 funciones que hacen lo mismo solo que se les pasa distintos elementos de un objeto para poder ordenarlas en una tabla de manera ascendente o descendente. Por ejemplo:

```
function sortingNames(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    if (o1.first_name > o2.first_name) {
      return 1; 
    } else if (o1.first_name < o2.first_name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
function sortingLastNames(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    if (o1.last_name > o2.last_name) {
      return 1; 
    } else if (o1.last_name < o2.last_name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
```

Estas 2 funciones son casi los mismo solo por las variables `first_name` y `last_name` . No quiero repetirme ya intente agregando un argumento a la función pero no funciona

```js
const infoTable = document.getElementById('info-table');
const sortName = document.getElementById('sort-name');
const sortLastName = document.getElementById('sort-last-name');
const sortAge = document.getElementById('sort-age');
const sortID = document.getElementById('sort-id');
const apiURL = "https://random-data-api.com/api/users/random_user?size=";
const size = 10;

let listUsers = [];

// Calculating the age
function getAge(dateBirth) {
  const today = new Date();
  const birthday = new Date(dateBirth);
  let age = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth(); 
  
  if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < birthday.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  
  return age;
}

// Sort Strings
function sortingNames(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    if (o1.first_name > o2.first_name) {
      return 1; 
    } else if (o1.first_name < o2.first_name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
function sortingLastNames(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    if (o1.last_name > o2.last_name) {
      return 1; 
    } else if (o1.last_name < o2.last_name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}

// Reverse Strings
function insortingNames(arr) {
  arr.reverse(function(o1, o2) {
    if (o1.first_name > o2.first_name) {
      return 1; 
    } else if (o1.first_name < o2.first_name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
function insortingLastNames(arr) {
  arr.reverse(function(o1, o2) {
    if (o1.first_name > o2.first_name) {
      return 1; 
    } else if (o1.first_name < o2.first_name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}

// Sort ID's
function sortingID(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.id - o2.id;
  });
}

// Reverse ID's
function insortingID(arr) {
  arr.sort(function (o1, o2) {
    return o2.id - o1.id;
  })
}

// Showing data on the table with this function
const displayInfo = (users) => {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    const { first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, address, id, email } = user;

    const age = getAge(date_of_birth);
  

    infoTable.innerHTML += `
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">${first_name}</td>
        <td role="cell">${last_name}</td>
        <td role="cell">${age}</td>
        <td role="cell">${address.country}</td>
        <td role="cell">${id}</td>
        <td role="cell">${email}</td>
      </tr>
    `
  });
}

// Getting Data from API Random
async function getInfoUsers() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiURL}${size}`);
    const result = await response.json();

    listUsers = [...result];
    
    displayInfo(result);
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

getInfoUsers();

// Event
sortName.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  sortName.classList.toggle('abc');
  infoTable.innerHTML = '';
  
  if (sortName.classList.contains('abc')) {
    sortingNames(listUsers);

    displayInfo(listUsers);
  } else {
    insortingNames(listUsers);

    displayInfo(listUsers);
  }

});
sortLastName.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  sortLastName.classList.toggle('abc');
  infoTable.innerHTML= '';

  if (sortLastName.classList.contains('abc')) {
    sortingLastNames(listUsers);

    displayInfo(listUsers);
  } else {
    insortingLastNames(listUsers);

    displayInfo(listUsers);
  }
});
sortID.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
  sortID.classList.toggle('abc');
  infoTable.innerHTML = '';

  if (sortID.classList.contains('abc')) {
    sortingID(listUsers);
    
    displayInfo(listUsers);
  } else {
    insortingID(listUsers);

    displayInfo(listUsers);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400&display=swap");

/* Reset */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eef0f1, #87888a); 
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem;
}

thead {
  background-color: #e9d2e5;
}

/* Desktop */
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 95%;
}

th, td {
  width: 250px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f4f4f7;
}

.content-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  
}

.content-table thead tr {
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
}

.content-table thead tr p {
  display: inline-block;
}


th, td {
  border: 1px solid #87888a;
}

.content-table thead tr th {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0.7rem 0.5rem 0.7rem 0.5rem;
}

td {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.header-line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

i {
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Responsive */
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none; for accesibility */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }

  /* Adding space between rows-groups */
  tr {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }

  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc;
  }

  td {
    /* Behave like a row */
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%; 
  }

  td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.63rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name" }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name" }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Age" }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Nation" }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "ID" }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "E-Mail" }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1b3aa506e9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="R4.css">
  <title>Solicitud R4</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <table class="content-table" role="table">
    <thead role="rowgroup">
      <tr role="row">
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Name</p><i id="sort-name" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Last Name</p><i id="sort-last-name" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Age</p><i id="sort-age" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Nation</p></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>ID</p><i id="sort-id" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>E-Mail</p></div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="info-table" role="rowgroup">
      <!-- <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">James</td>
        <td role="cell">Matman</td>
        <td role="cell">45</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">43453456</td>
        <td role="cell">jame@jame.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Carl</td>
        <td role="cell">Deck</td>
        <td role="cell">33</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">4345645456</td>
        <td role="cell">carl@deck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Laura</td>
        <td role="cell">Dickson</td>
        <td role="cell">25</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">46753956</td>
        <td role="cell">laura@dickson.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Ema</td>
        <td role="cell">Bostian</td>
        <td role="cell">29</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">41253856</td>
        <td role="cell">ema@bostian.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Jaz</td>
        <td role="cell">Breackman</td>
        <td role="cell">31</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">98453456</td>
        <td role="cell">jaz@breackman.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Lito</td>
        <td role="cell">Costafebre</td>
        <td role="cell">56</td>
        <td role="cell">ARG</td>
        <td role="cell">47753456</td>
        <td role="cell">lito@costa.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Rod</td>
        <td role="cell">Stewart</td>
        <td role="cell">57</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">99453456</td>
        <td role="cell">rod@stewart.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Tara</td>
        <td role="cell">Walsh</td>
        <td role="cell">21</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">1473456</td>
        <td role="cell">tara@walsh.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Dua</td>
        <td role="cell">Lipa</td>
        <td role="cell">23</td>
        <td role="cell">UK</td>
        <td role="cell">434021456</td>
        <td role="cell">dua@lipa.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Enzo</td>
        <td role="cell">Perez</td>
        <td role="cell">31</td>
        <td role="cell">ARG</td>
        <td role="cell">40053456</td>
        <td role="cell">enzo@perez.com</td>
      </tr> -->
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="R4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciertamente, se puede simplificar el código, no solo en evitar funciones casi iguales, también en otras cosas, como usar la variable global `listUsers` en vez de pasarla como parámetro, no es necesario y te sugiero hacer el cambio para evitar confusiones o variables extra.

En cuanto a:

> No quiero repetirme ya intente agregando un argumento a la función pero no funciona

No basta con enviar el argumento, sino la forma de usarlo, por ejemplo, si el argumento es `'first_name'`, debes usarlo como índice para acceder a la propiedad correspondiente:

```
function miFuncion(property) {
    // Esto no va a funcionar, porque se intentará acceder a listUsers.property, que no existe
    console.log(listUsers.property);
    // Debes usar el argumento como índice, será como acceder a listUsers.first_name o listUsers['first_name'], que es lo mismo
    console.log(listUsers[property]);
}
```

Con dos funciones es suficiente para ordenar por las columnas que quieras, en cada una envías el nombre de propiedad y si el orden debe ser ascendente o descendente.

```js
const infoTable = document.getElementById('info-table');
const sortName = document.getElementById('sort-name');
const sortLastName = document.getElementById('sort-last-name');
const sortAge = document.getElementById('sort-age');
const sortID = document.getElementById('sort-id');
const apiURL = "https://random-data-api.com/api/users/random_user?size=";
const size = 10;

let listUsers = [];

// Calculating the age
function getAge(dateBirth) {
  const today = new Date();
  const birthday = new Date(dateBirth);
  let age = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth(); 
  
  if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < birthday.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  
  return age;
}

// Ordenar por propiedad de tipo cadena
// arr - Es el arreglo a ordenar
// property - Es la propiedad que se va a usar para ordenar
// reverse - Verdadero para orden descendente
function sortString(arr, property, reverse = false) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => a[property].localeCompare(b[property]));
    // Invertir arreglo cuando el parámetro sea verdadero
    if(reverse) {
        arr.reverse();
    }
}
// Funciona igual que la anterior, pero es específica para datos numéricos
function sortNumber(arr, property, reverse = false) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => a[property] - b[property]);
    if(reverse) {
        arr.reverse();
    }
}


// Showing data on the table with this function
const displayInfo = (users) => {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    const { first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, address, id, email } = user;

    const age = getAge(date_of_birth);
  

    infoTable.innerHTML += `
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">${first_name}</td>
        <td role="cell">${last_name}</td>
        <td role="cell">${age}</td>
        <td role="cell">${address.country}</td>
        <td role="cell">${id}</td>
        <td role="cell">${email}</td>
      </tr>
    `
  });
}

// Getting Data from API Random
async function getInfoUsers() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiURL}${size}`);
    const result = await response.json();

    listUsers = [...result];
    
    displayInfo(result);
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

getInfoUsers();

// Event
sortName.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sortName.classList.toggle('abc');
  infoTable.innerHTML = '';
  // Orden inverso si no contiene la clase abc
  let reverse = !sortName.classList.contains('abc');
  // Ordenar y mostrar
  sortString(listUsers, 'first_name', reverse);
  displayInfo(listUsers);
});

sortLastName.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sortLastName.classList.toggle('abc');
  infoTable.innerHTML= '';

  let reverse = !sortLastName.classList.contains('abc');
  sortString(listUsers, 'last_name', reverse);
  displayInfo(listUsers);
});

sortID.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sortID.classList.toggle('abc');
  infoTable.innerHTML = '';

  let reverse = !sortID.classList.contains('abc');
  sortNumber(listUsers, 'id', reverse);
  displayInfo(listUsers);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400&display=swap");

/* Reset */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eef0f1, #87888a); 
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem;
}

thead {
  background-color: #e9d2e5;
}

/* Desktop */
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 95%;
}

th, td {
  width: 250px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f4f4f7;
}

.content-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  
}

.content-table thead tr {
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
}

.content-table thead tr p {
  display: inline-block;
}


th, td {
  border: 1px solid #87888a;
}

.content-table thead tr th {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0.7rem 0.5rem 0.7rem 0.5rem;
}

td {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.header-line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

i {
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Responsive */
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none; for accesibility */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }

  /* Adding space between rows-groups */
  tr {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }

  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc;
  }

  td {
    /* Behave like a row */
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%; 
  }

  td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 0;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0.63rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name" }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name" }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Age" }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Nation" }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "ID" }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "E-Mail" }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1b3aa506e9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="R4.css">
  <title>Solicitud R4</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <table class="content-table" role="table">
    <thead role="rowgroup">
      <tr role="row">
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Name</p><i id="sort-name" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Last Name</p><i id="sort-last-name" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Age</p><i id="sort-age" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>Nation</p></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>ID</p><i id="sort-id" class="fas fa-sort"></i></div></th>
        <th role="columnheader"><div class="header-line"><p>E-Mail</p></div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="info-table" role="rowgroup">
      <!-- <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">James</td>
        <td role="cell">Matman</td>
        <td role="cell">45</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">43453456</td>
        <td role="cell">jame@jame.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Carl</td>
        <td role="cell">Deck</td>
        <td role="cell">33</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">4345645456</td>
        <td role="cell">carl@deck.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Laura</td>
        <td role="cell">Dickson</td>
        <td role="cell">25</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">46753956</td>
        <td role="cell">laura@dickson.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Ema</td>
        <td role="cell">Bostian</td>
        <td role="cell">29</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">41253856</td>
        <td role="cell">ema@bostian.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Jaz</td>
        <td role="cell">Breackman</td>
        <td role="cell">31</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">98453456</td>
        <td role="cell">jaz@breackman.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Lito</td>
        <td role="cell">Costafebre</td>
        <td role="cell">56</td>
        <td role="cell">ARG</td>
        <td role="cell">47753456</td>
        <td role="cell">lito@costa.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Rod</td>
        <td role="cell">Stewart</td>
        <td role="cell">57</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">99453456</td>
        <td role="cell">rod@stewart.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Tara</td>
        <td role="cell">Walsh</td>
        <td role="cell">21</td>
        <td role="cell">USA</td>
        <td role="cell">1473456</td>
        <td role="cell">tara@walsh.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Dua</td>
        <td role="cell">Lipa</td>
        <td role="cell">23</td>
        <td role="cell">UK</td>
        <td role="cell">434021456</td>
        <td role="cell">dua@lipa.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr role="row">
        <td role="cell">Enzo</td>
        <td role="cell">Perez</td>
        <td role="cell">31</td>
        <td role="cell">ARG</td>
        <td role="cell">40053456</td>
        <td role="cell">enzo@perez.com</td>
      </tr> -->
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="R4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y todavía se puede reducir si creas una función para que los eventos no repitan código, por ejemplo:

```
function eventOrder(column, property, type = '') {
    // Limpiar la tabla
    infoTable.innerHTML = '';
    // Cambiar clase de la columna
    column.classList.toggle('abc');
    // Orden inverso si no contiene la clase abc
    let reverse = !column.classList.contains('abc');
    // Ordenar por cadena o número, dependiendo del tipo
    if(type == 'string') {
        sortString(listUsers, property, reverse);
    } else {
        sortNumber(listUsers, property, reverse);
    }
    // Actualizar tabla
    displayInfo(listUsers);
}

// La asignación de eventos queda con una sola línea
sortName.addEventListener('click', () => {
    eventOrder(sortName, 'first_name', 'string');
});
```

Comment: Muy bueno solo voy a tener que agregar los events que faltan. Está perfecto gracias!